# GroundOverlay just like javascript in android

Tags: android, dictionary, bitmap, overlay, android-mapview

I am trying to create a ground overlay similar as those available in web APIs provided by Google.

I came across these on StackOverflow

[does-android-maps-support-ground-overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999907/does-android-maps-support-ground-overlay)

[android-google-maps-groundoverlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595313/android-google-maps-groundoverlay)

I have implemented both of them with a bit of tweaking, but problem is same with both of them. When area is large to cover especially when zoomed in at high levels I get VMBudget error and application crashes.

I have tried all the tuning while scaling bitmaps for the overlay, like recycling and using BitmapOptions, but no success.

The sole issue is 16 MB VM Budget proves to be insufficient for the scaling at runtime more than 3500px image is required at max zoom in  my case and since draw() overlay calls almost every ms its eating up.

I need a solution which can crop image to the screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I searched and I implemented everything I know. But I think the only way out of this,

**OSM Droid**
http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/FAQ

User tiles feature of the API and attain the required result